# Not understanding simple mathematical (no fancy stuff) solution to a task

Tags: algorithms

The problem sounds like that:

> Kevin has N friends and one building. He wants to organize a
>   party in that building and he invites exacly *1 friend / day*. Kevin
>   unfortunately has grumpy neighbors which aren't too happy with the
>   noise that Kevin's party does. For that, Kevin wants to minimize the
>   noise level of his party. (the noise level is equal to the number of
>   friends in the building) In order to do that, after some day he can
>   clear the building by asking his friends to leave (**he can do that K times, for K different days**). (*ex*: he clears the
>   building after day 2 so at day 3 when he invites another friend, for
>   day 3 the noise level will be 1 because the past day he cleared the
>   building; if he didn't clear the building at day 2, the noise level
>   for day 3 will have been 3 (1 from day 2, 1 from day 1 and the new invited friend) and the total noise level for day 1, 2 and 3 would have been 1+2+3=6).

For better understanding the task:

**Input:**

```
5 2 (N, K)
```

**Output:**

```
7
```

**Explanation:**

In the input example, N friends will be invited at the party, in the following order:

```
1 (day 1)                                                       1 (day 1)
1 (day 2)    so in the building for each day will be present    2 (day 2)
1 (day 3)   ------------------------------------------------->  3 (day 3)
1 (day 4)          (without clearing the building)              4 (day 4)
1 (day 5)                                                       5 (day 5)
                                                             -----(+)
                                                               15
```

So, clearing the building 0 times (**K=0**), the noise level will be 15.

Clearing the building 1 time (**K=1**), the sum will be:

```
(0 times)
    1                                              1
 __ 2 __     clearing the building after day 2     2
    3       ----------------------------------->   1
    4                                              2
    5                                              3
                                                 ----(+)
                                                   9
```

At this case (K=1), another solution could be to clear after day 3, same sum.

Clearing 2 times (**K=2**):

```
(0 times)
    1                                                  1
 __ 2 __     clearing the building after day 2 & 3     2
 __ 3 __    -------------------------------------->    1
    4                                                  1
    5                                                  2
                                                     ----(+)
                                                       7
```

---

I have the solution but I don't understand it!

I tried, took some other cases but still nothing, maybe you guys can explain me why the solution is the way it is.

This is how sum(N, K) is calculated:

> sum(N, K) = minimum noise level clearing the building K times (K>=0)

**C++ code:**

```
int sum(int n)
 {
    return n * (n + 1) / 2;
 }

int solve(int n, int k)
{
    int p = k + 1;
    int mp = n/p;
    int bp = (n+p-1)/p;
    int nmaj = n%p;
    int nmic = p-nmaj;

    return nmic * sum(mp) + nmaj*sum(bp);
}
```

What is the purpose of each variable?

What does `nmic * sum(mp)` and `nmaj*sum(bp)` computes?

**!!!!**

For the example above (at the beginning - N=5, K=2), I debugged the code and wrote for `N=5, K=0..2` the value for each variable, hoping to get the idea but no succes. I am going to post them for you, maybe you'll get the idea and then explain to me (I am a novice in algorithmic problems).

Here is it:

**[variable values for each case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WVM8.png)**

I repeat, I tried for some hours to understand but no succes. And it's not a homework. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assumption behind this program for finding a solution is that the optimal thing is to divide the $N$ days into $K+1$ periods as evenly as possible.

I.e., if you have $N=12$ days and you can clear $K=2$ times, the best thing is to have $K+1=3$ periods of $12/3 = 4$ days each.

If the days where $N=13$ then the best thing was to have one period of $5$ days and the other two periods of $4$ days each.

This is what the functions does. It takes $n$ days, it divides that in $p=k+1$ periods. Among these, $p$ periods there will be a certain number of periods of length $c$ and other of length $c+1$ (if $n$ is not divisible by $p$).

Example, $n=17$ and $k=4$. You have $k+1=5$ periods. The division will be $3$ periods of length $3$ and the remaining two periods of length $4$. Indeed $3\cdot3 +2\cdot4=17$.

The function sum(n) simply computes the cumulate noise over $n$ days. It is the $n$-th triangular number $1+2+\cdots+n$ which is equal to $n(n+1)/2$.

A main ingredient of this program is that in C language if you compute $a/b$ between positive integers, the result is $\lfloor a/b\rfloor$, i.e., the integer part of the division.

Let's analyze function solve.

```
int p=k+1;
int  mp = n/p;
```

Here $p$ is simply $k+1$, i.e., the number of periods in which we want to divide $n$. The variable $mp$, which is equal to $\lfloor n/p\rfloor$, it is simply the number of consecutive days you will get if $n$ is divisible by $p$, i.e., if there is not rest in the division $n/p$.

For example, if $n=17$ and you want to divide that in $p=5$ periods you get $mp=3$, because in a solution with $5$ periods you will have the least periods equal to $3$.

```
int bp = (n+p-1)/p;
```

This  computes the length of the longer periods. If $n$ is a multiple of $p$, then $\lfloor(n+p-1)/p$ will be equal to $n/p$, because adding $p-1$ to $n$ is not enough to reach the next multiple of $p$.

Instead, if $n$ is not a precise multiple of $p$, we will have $\lfloor(n+p-1)/p = \lfloor n/p\rfloor + 1$.

So, if $n=17$ and $p=5$, we have $mp=3$ and $bp=4$ (because $17$ is not a multiple of $5$).

If $n=20$ and $p=5$, we have $mp=bp=4$ because $20$ is a multiple of $5$.

So now we have computed how many days are in the short periods ($mp$) and how many days in the long periods ($bp$) (and $mp=bp$ if $n$ is a multiple of $p$).

Now we have just to compute how many short and how many long periods are there.

```
int nmaj=n%p;
```

This simply compute the remainder in the division $n/p$. This will be the number of long periods. It could be $0$.

The number of short periods will be equal to the number of periods minus $nmaj$, i.e.,

```
int nmic=p-nmaj;
```

Now we can compute the total of noise. We have $nmic$ periods of $mp$ days each, and $nmaj$ periods of $bp$ days each, hence the total is

```
return nmic * sum(mp) + nmaj*sum(bp);
```